# What's the best library to generate random numbers for cryptographic keys in .NET?

Tags: .net, random

In .NET, you can generate RSA key pairs using RSACryptoServiceProvide. But is that the best option in .NET to generate truly random numbers? There are tons of other open source libraries, such as CryptoPlusPlus, that can be used to generate random number. I would like to hear from other experts' opinions. Thanks in advance for your two cents.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't personally go anywhere other than RNGCryptoServiceProvider unless somebody provides a proof that it sucks.

The actual implementation used by this class is not obtainable because it's implemented as part of the runtime (`System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._GetBytes` or `System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._GetNonZeroBytes`) which, for me, is heartening since I would hope that the implementation would bring at least ambient information in from the host to generate the data.

I do believe these are routed through to lower level win32 apis which, of course, would be patched if a security hole is found in them (well... hopefully!)

How it's done in Mono, however, I wouldn't know.

***For the extremely paranoid***

The real problem with any of this is that your randomness in .Net can be broken by a malicious hacker by changing the host behaviour (that is - by writing a modified runtime).  This is much easier in a VM-style platform like .Net or Java than it is in native code (which would require hacking the lower-level platform or modifying the hardware).

Curiously, using RNGCryptoServiceProvider makes this a lot easier since these aforementioned internal calls are implicitly trusted by the managed part of the .Net framework.

However - in reality - your code is going to have to be something really special for someone to want to go to all that effort.  So personally I'd still use RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

But it's why I have a real problem with attempts a crypto libraries and functions written in javascript - a quick browser hack can screw it all.

Comment: Actually, predicting random numbers generated by the host system is pretty easy. Cheat coder have done that with many anti-cheat tools which create screenshots at random times. They just got the seed in memory and predicted the next random numbers. Ive never implemented such a method, but ive seen that working.

Comment: @fielding: I'll bet! Having read the excellent chapter in Practical Cryptography (http://www.schneier.com/book-practical.html) on generating Randomness it's such a minefield that it's easy to just give up! If only I had a cosmic ray detector...

Answer (score 1):

Classes derived from [`RandomNumberGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) generate truly random numbers.

Comment: * as random as we can get with deterministic algorithms.

Comment: Also: From the documentation: "Application code does not directly use this class. This abstract class is provided as the base class for all cryptographic random number generators."

Comment: Is there any proof that the derived class of RandomNumberGenerator, such as RNGCyrptowareServiceProvide, is better than library where you can feed in random seed from external source.

Comment: Actually - depending on the machine hardware - `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` may not be dependent on "deterministic algorithms".

Comment: @weilin8: No. On the Windows platform, the standard practice is to include a CSP if you have a source of truly random data. Otherwise (e.g., most machines), the OS will use a deterministic algorithm incorporating a wide variety of inputs to get a very close approximation of randomness. It does a better job of this than we could, so if the "random seed" is just things like mouse movements, it's definitely better left up to windows. If you do have an actual *random* source that's not a CSP for some reason, then you would be better to use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could get them from random.org if your project allows that. That should be random enough.